# get post content and display in a page by matching the page name and post category name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing some little hacks for wordpress by giving myself some used cases. I think that is the best way to learn this

I have created a scenario where I am checking if the page name is 'x' then fetch contents of posts categorized as 'y' in the page x. Works fine as long as I hard code the page names like this

```
if(is_page('x')){
    query_posts('category_name=y');
}
```

Now I am thinking what if I generalize the x and retrieve all the categories and push them in an array. Iterate through the array and look for match like

```
if(pageName == postCategoryName){
query_posts('category_name=the correct category');
}
```

I believe I would basically have to create the post categories with the same name as the page name

Conceptually I am good with this but when it is coming to the syntax I am getting a bit lost. How should I approach this?

Comment: So if you have a page called Blog posts you want to display all the posts with the category of articles or are all the page names the same as the categories name?

Comment: @Howlin--I am planning to create a situation of 1:1 mapping. So lets say..I will name the pages as blog, history, geography
and post categories as blog, history, geography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved by getting the slug of the current page and then finding the same slug in a category.

e.g. if you were on the Geography page

```
$slug = basename(get_permalink());
```

$slug would contain `geography` so you can query that by:

```
query_posts("category_name={$slug}");
```

And that should return the posts in the category.